# How do you use multiple typeConfigs in Unity?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

In unity, when configuring a type, you can specify more than one typeConfig if uniquely named like so:

```
<type type="IFoo" mapTo="ConcreteFoo">
    <typeConfig name="rainbows">
        <constructor>
            <param name="magic" parameterType="string">
                <value value="rainbows"/>
            </param>
        </constructor>
    </typeConfig>
    <typeConfig name="unicorns>
        <constructor>
            <param name="magic" parameterType="string">
                <value value="unicorns"/>
            </param>
        </constructor>
    </typeConfig>
</type>
```

When resolving, how do you specify which typeConfig, and consequently what gets injected to the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply the name in a DependencyAttribute, like this:

```
[Dependency("unicorns")]
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't that tie ConcreteFoo to a particular typeConfig at class design time and not resove time?

Comment: Yes, with the DependencyAttribute, the attributed member will be bound to "unicorns" at compile time. Is suppose I don't understand your requirement. How do you want to decide which instance your constructor gets?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how multiple typeConfigs could be used at run/resolve time.

Comment: The only way to do that in Unity is to call Resolve in your code. You can't do it with constructor or setter injection.

Answer (score 0):

When you call container.Resolve, you can pass a string. That string is the name that you used to configure a particular registration.

Also, when you configure registrations, you can specify the dependencyName on a registration to tell it which named registration you want the container to use.